# run docker commands from command prompt versus jenkins script

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have a test Ubuntu server with docker-machine installed.  I have a number of docker containers running on the servers.  Including a Jenkins container.  I run jenkins with the following command

```
docker run -d --name jenkins -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker --restart=always -p 8080:8080 -v ~/jenkinsHome:/var/jenkins_home docker-jenkins
```

I am working on managing my images through Jenkins.  I can start all but one of my containers via Jenkins shell script.  The one container that fails appears to start in the script (I do a docker PS after the docker run in script).  However, the container stops after the script completes.  I am using the same docker run command that works on the command prompt, but it fails in Jenkins script:

```
sudo docker run -d --net=host -v ~/plex-config:/config -v ~/Media:/media -p 32400:32400 wernight/plex-media-server
```

I have double checked folder permissions and they are correct.  Can anyone direct me to possible reasons the run command is failing in Jenkins, but not at the command prompt?

Comment: As a side note: there is no point using `-p 32400:32400` when you also use `--net=host`. When `--net=host` is used, all ports opened on the container will be opened on the docker host

Comment: Could you share the output of `docker logs` for the container that fails to start in jenkins?

Comment: what is the use account docker slave running? Does it have sudo permissions correct? Any other environment parameters different?

Comment: @Thomasleveil how do I get those logs?  The container stops before I can exec into it?  And thanks for the note about the port.  I was just following the instructions provided by the developer of the image.

Comment: `docker ps -a` to list all containers including stopped ones. Then `docker logs <id of stopped container>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `docker ps -a` I was able to get an ID for the stopped container.  Then by using `docker logs` I was able to see the error was a folder permission issue.  Then digging deeper, it was a user permission error mis-match between the user Jenkins runs as inside it's container not being able to pass the folder correctly.  I have decided to circumvent the problem by using docker stop and start commands and not using the docker run command.